# output-dir with texlive and gvim

Tags: vim, latex, latex-suite, tex-live

I am usgin latex-suit for `gvim`.
I want to use the output-dir option.
I defined:

```
let g:Tex_MultipleCompileFormats='pdf'
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex --output-directory=output --synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

The problem is that with the `--output-directory` options latex-suit does not compile multiple times if it necesary, only once. And, I have to compile it manually if references changes.

How can I configure latex-suit multiple compile options with the `--output-directory`?

Answer (score 2):

You have two options: use a makefile (which I would recommend) or run the command several times inside `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf`.

#### Use a Makefile

LaTeX documents, when they become big, may be troublesome to manage:

- several BibTeX reference files,
- gnuplot graphs that are compiled differently in `{draft}` mode,
- and general `\input` documents.

If you try to manage that with a single command line it will quickly become impossible to maintain.  Using a Makefile allows for better dependency checking between files and also Vim can compile the LaTeX document with `:make` (with the default `:makeprg`, which is set to `make`).  An example Makefile could be like the following:

```
# Makefile for my LaTeX doc

LATEX  = pdflatex -output-directory=output -synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode
BIBTEX = bibtex
RM     = rm -f
BIB    = mybibs.bib
LTFS   = *.aux *.lof *.log *.lot *.fls *.out *.toc
DOCS   = *.dvi *.pdf
BIBS   = *.bbl *.blg
IDXS   = *.idx *.ilg *.ind *.ist
OTHER  = *.acn *.acr *.glg *.glo *.gls *.brf *.lol

all: document.pdf

%.pdf: %.tex %.bbl
    $(LATEX) $<
    $(LATEX) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.aux
%.aux: %.tex
    $(LATEX) $<

.PRECIOUS: %.bbl
%.bbl: %.aux $(BIB)
    $(BIBTEX) $<

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(LTFS) $(DOCS) $(BIBS) $(IDXS) $(OTHER)
```

This Makefile runs `pdflatex` two times by default: once to build the sections and page numbers and a second time to make proper cross references.  If a reference changes the `.aux` file will be changed and `pdflatex` will be run three times.

If you do not use BibTeX you do not need the parts about `%.bbl` files.

#### Put several commands into `g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf`

I'll once again warn that this will quickly become unmaintainable.  Tracking dependencies between files through a very long command line is very difficult.

Anyhow, you can use `$*` several times inside an external command in Vim.  In essence you can do this:

```
let g:Tex_CompileRule_pdf = 'pdflatex -output-directory=output '
  \. '-synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*; '
  \. 'pdflatex -output-directory=output '
  \. '-synctex=-1 -src-specials -interaction=nonstopmode $*'
```

And it will run `pdflatex` twice (note the semicolon) when you press `<leader>ll`.

---

Extra note: we do have the [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com) section of the website for Vim specific questions.  It is often faster to get Vim related answers there.

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try to use makefiles.